# Can Firefox or Chromium (as of 2023) be tricked to accept SSLv3 for a specified local IP (an old iRMC)?

Tags: ssl, remote-access, ipmi

I'm fiddling around with an older Fujitsu server running iRMC S3.
The integrated webserver does only allow SSLv3 to be enabled due to it's age and can of course not be updated beyond it's current state.

Of course latest Firefox and Chromium do not allow connections to the web interface if that option is enabled.

While falling back to an older Browser release is an option, I'd prefer to get it running in a current browser.

Any hints and tricks that I found so far are pretty much outdated.

I'm fully aware that SSLv3 poses some risks - this side of the medal should not be the topic here actually.

So the question is: can a current version of Firefox or Chromium be tricked to accept SSLv3 (at best only for a specified local IP address)?

Comment: Unlikely. I doubt that support for SSLv3 is even built into these browsers anymore, so no switch will make it possible to enable. That's at least true with OpenSSL, which by default does not include support for SSLv3 in the compiled library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain no :

- It is removed entirely from Firefox as of [Firefox 39](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1106470)
- Same for Chrome as of [40](https://codereview.chromium.org/649413004)

IE11 still seems to support it though (but you need to [enable](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/108679/249369) it)